# Изменение числа jquery

Tags: jquery

Например, есть на моем сайте число 1 и через три минуты оно должно замениться на 2, затем через три минуты должно замениться на три)
Я применяю jquery. 
В head пишу

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
var startNum = 1;
setInterval(function(){ 
$('#num').html(startNum);
startNum += 1;
}, 300000);
});
```

</script>

В body пишу

```
<span id="num"></span>
```

Но, не работает. Почему?

Comment: Он  на document rady, поэтому не поможет.

Comment: 1 минута = 60 секунд, а не 100, как у Вас в коде.

Answer (score 1):

Думаю вы просто не можете дождаться 300000 миллисекунд.

Comment: @viboxjuwin, Кстати да, 3мин. это 180 000 миллисекунд.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/4uRKT/

```
<span id="numtag">0</span>
<script>
   num = 0;
   setInterval(function(){
      num++;
      document.getElementById('numtag').innerHTML = num;
   }, 1000);    
</script>
```

Comment: Ребята, большое человеческое спасибо! Может кто подсказать, как заставить это число не обновляться при обновлении страницы? То есть ушел со страницы, а отсчет продолжается..

Comment: Можно в localStorage или в Cookie положить, тут без костылей не обойдёшься.

Comment: А если пых использовать по аналогии?

Comment: @viboxjuwin, Да.
Как и любой серверный код)